# How to use Machine.Fakes.Moq to verify that a method was called?

Tags: machine.fakes

I am using Machine.Fakes.Moq and I want to verify that a method of an interface was called. What would be the right way to verify it. I want to verify that the method was called with a parameter of a specific type lets say string.

Can anyone please tell me the syntax for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Figured it out,

Here is the syntax

```
Object.WasToldTo(s => s.MethodName(Param.IsAny<String>()));
```